# How to send 2 Keys By python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code like this and the strings in file like that(
khaled ali
mohamed ali
jhon wick)

how can i send the first name and second by this code

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
     i = random.randrange(len(lines))
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(lines[i])
```

Comment: every string in a line

Comment: Are there strings in seperate lines? In names.txt?

Comment: Yes, like that 

(hamed hany)

but every name in a line

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. You want to send only the first names (mohamed, john...) or only the second names (ali, wick)? If that, you should use the split metho of Python strings. Every element in lines is a string, so you can use string.split() and get a list with two elements (first name and second name). Otherwise, please clarify yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.